# HTML: Why doesn't Firefox use wrap="off" when set by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, word-wrap

I'm using this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('textarea').attr('wrap', 'off');
});
```

(JQuery) (Firefox 3.5)

I'm checking with WebDeveloper that the wrap attribute indeed is set to off in the page when I'm loading it up, but the text still wraps. If I hard-code the invalid HTML of `wrap="off"` into the `<textarea>` in my HTML, it works fine, but this is invalid HTML and I'm not interested in doing that. When using spellcheck="false" in JavaScript you actually have to pass it the keyword false instead of a string "false". I tried to apply this same principle using false instead of "off", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a phenomenon happening with Firefox and Opera. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263938/changing-textarea-wrapping-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Pekka. Didn't see that one.