# Disabling line wrapping in a TextArea

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I'm using GWT 2.1.  I have a `TextArea` that I'm using to preview a document, and I don't want lines that are too long to fit to wrap - I want a horizontal scrollbar to appear.

There's no setWrap method I can find in `TextArea` - how can I achieve this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263938/changing-textarea-wrapping-using-javascript, which has some more information on wrapping the textarea html tag and issues with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
textArea.getElement().setAttribute("wrap", "off");
```